# Validation on MongoDB Morphia UpdateOperations

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have the following entity which uses morphia validation.

```
@Entity("users")
public class User {

    @Id ObjectId id;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=8)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Validation works when creating or replacing entire documents. How can I make the validation to work with MongoOperations?

Example:

UpdateOperations op = ...

op.set('email', 'INVALID_EMAIL');
op.set('password', 'INVALID PASSWORD');

Validation only works on null values, but it doesn't work on other validators.

Is there an easy way how to make this work?